# Editing (my own) decompiled source code - Java (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, backup

Kia ora,

I failed to back up my Java (IntelliJ) project *during the period I need to revert to*. I have a `*.jar` version of the project, which would serve me well, but I need to be able to edit the internal files to compare the behaviour of my current version and the old version.

My current thinking is to copy the FernFlower source recreation from the decompiled `.class` files (via IntelliJ) into a new project, along with duplicates of the files I know I haven't changed. Unsure if this would work, however.

Any better alternatives **much** appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower provides a CLI interface for outputting the source folder then you could use a tool to diff it and revert your previous code.

Comment: Per OP: I’m using FernFlower to generate ‘.source’ files, but my issue is generating ‘.java’ files so I can edit the internal code. If you know of such “tools”, please let me know.

Comment: The FernFlower can generate the jar including all `.java` code in it. I am not sure why you say the `.source` file here. You could also open this http://www.javadecompilers.com/ page, and scroll page down to see similar tools to generate the `.java` files.

Comment: I had previously tried FernFlower to generate the `.java` files, but it failed to generate them all. Procyon has worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I use on ubuntu. Recursively goes through what rootDir looking for .jar and decompiles them in the directory of said .jar file with said .jar files name as new folder. From there it changes .class file to .java in said new folder.

I dont have any options set. I'm just using this to try and generate a new client sdk api based of a terrible given api spec from a vendor.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the root directory containing your .jar files. Mine is backup of a server with a ton of .jar files to maintain existing folder structure.
rootDir="./6.4.0"

# Specify the path to your Java decompiler (FernFlower, CFR, etc.)
fernflowerPath="./java-decompiler.jar"

# Find all .jar files and loop over them.
find "$rootDir" -type f -name "*.jar" | while read -r jarFile; do
    echo "Decompiling $jarFile..."
    
    # Compute the output directory based on the jarFile path.
    outputDir="${jarFile%.*}"
    
    # Create the output directory if it doesn't exist.
    mkdir -p "$outputDir"
    
    # Run the decompiler.
    # Adjust the command line according to the decompiler you're using.
    java -cp "$fernflowerPath" org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler "$jarFile" "$outputDir"
    
    # Check if decompilation was successful.
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Successfully decompiled to $outputDir"
    else
        echo "Decompilation failed for $jarFile"
    fi
done
```